# notification disappear when home button clicked

Tags: android, notifications

MY application displays notification when it is running. But when I click the home button (the application is still running in the background) the notification disappears.
What should I do to keep it as is until the user clicks on it.
Thanks

```
   private void showNotification() {

    // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this
    // notification
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            serviceIntent, 0);


    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setTicker("Accelormeter app").setContentTitle("Acc")
            .setContentText("Notification content.")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.noti_icon).setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .getNotification();




    // Send the notification.
    mNM.notify(0, notification);

}
```

Comment: where is your code? show us what you tried

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `getNotification();`  instead use `build();` in the Notification.Builder